# Python sql query from associative entity result to 2d pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, associative

I would like to populate a pandas dataframe from an sql table that is an associative entity so that the data frame has an index of one of the entities and column headers of the second entity.

So as an example, I have the following SQL tables:

Entity 1

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| A | Type A |
| B | Type B |

Entity 2

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| W | Type W |
| X | Type X |
| Y | Type Y |
| Z | Type Z |

Associative entity

| Entity 1_code | Entity 2_code | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | W | 1 |
| A | Y | 7 |
| A | Z | 3 |
| B | X | 88 |
| B | Y | 5 |

And I would like my dataframe to have the following structure

|  | W | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | NaN | 7 | 3 |
| B | NaN | 88 | 5 | NaN |

Semantically I can do this by loading an empty frame using following pseudo code:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect( ... )

# create empty df with index set to Entity 1 codes
df = psql.read_sql('SELECT code FROM entity_1', connection, index_col='code')

cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT code FROM entity_2')

# create list of column names
entity_2_codes = [r[0] for r in cur.fetchall()]
# add columns from entity 2 codes
df=df.reindex(columns=entity_2_codes) 

# now loop through each associative entity entry and insert value into dataframe
```

Is there a smart way that I can populate the table more efficiently? Add a column or a row at a time maybe? Note the data is sparse and so not every `Entity 1` x `Entity 2` combination will have a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pandas [pivot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) or [pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) methods. `pivot` is used when you don't need aggregation (there'll be only one value per `Entity 1_code` and `Entity 2_code` combination). `pivot_table` can be used to do aggregations (sum, count, max) if you have more than one value, you can specify how to fill NA values etc.

If you can load the `Associative entity` table into a DataFrame `df`, this would simply be:

```
df.pivot(index='Entity 1_code', columns='Entity 2_code', values='value')
```

or using `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Entity 1_code', columns='Entity 2_code', values='value', aggfunc='mean')
```

If there is only one value per combination, `pivot_table` can mimic `pivot` by setting the aggfunc to 'mean' as the average will just be that one value.

Comment: Thanks @user:14778905 thats very helpful Liam, perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can do this with conditional aggregation - but that requires that you know the list of codes beforehand:

```
select entity_1_code,
    max(case when entity_2code = 'W' then value end) as w,
    max(case when entity_2code = 'X' then value end) as x,
    max(case when entity_2code = 'Y' then value end) as y,
    max(case when entity_2code = 'Z' then value end) as z
from associative_entity
group by entity_1_code
```

Note that you don't need the two other tables to get the result that you are showing. But if you want to bring information from those tables, you can always `join` them in the above query.

Answer (score 0):

You could query the associative table only:

Then you can apply a simple `.pivot()` function

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Entity 1_code':['A', 'A','A', 'B', 'B'], 'Entity 2_code': ['W', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'Y'], 'code_value':[1,7,3,88,5]})
df.pivot(index='Entity 1_code', columns='Entity 2_code', values='code_value')
```